# Как редактировать данные в строках sqlite3, содержащих уникальный столбец?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

Есть функция, которая добавляет `message_id` (уникальный столбец) и `user` пользователя в базу данных. При этом помимо двух этих столбцов имеется третий столбец `status`:

```py
def add_mes(self, message_id, user):
"""Добавляем ФИО и message_id в БД"""
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `rasp` (`message_id`, `user`) VALUES (?, ?)", (message_id, user))
    return self.conn.commit()
```

вслед за этой функцией при нажатии клавиши должна запускаться следующая функция такая, чтобы в строке с вышеуказанным уникальным `message_id` отредактировался третий столбец `status`, а остальные данные остались теми же

```py
def add_status(self, message_id, status):
    """Добавляем статус дом/офис в БД"""
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `rasp` (`message_id`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?)", (message_id, status))
    return self.conn.commit()
```

выдает ошибку

> sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: rasp.user

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке явно указывает на то, что в данной таблице поле `user` не может быть пустым, а вы вторым запросом создаете новую запись с пустым `user`. Судя по описанию, вам нужно заменить `INSERT` на [`UPDATE`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm) во втором запросе и использовать в нем `WHERE message_id=(?)`, где (?) - message_id

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

решено следующим образом:

```
    def add_status(self, status, message_id):
        """Добавляем статус дом/офис в БД"""
        self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `rasp` SET `status` = ? WHERE `message_id` = ?", (status, message_id))
        return self.conn.commit()
```